# Guide me in the right direction of trying to connect two users together using a twitter bot

Tags: python, html

Looking for suggestions on how to connect 2 users together using my twitter bot. What I want is essentially, one user tweets at the bot and if it has the same information as what another person had tweeted at the bot, the bot tweets to each person; the tweet containing the matching person's username.

I've been able to make a variable out of the bot account's past tweet mentions and capture each mention's id and text.

```
mentions = api.mentions_timeline()

for mention in mentions:
    print(str(mention.id) + ' -- ' + mention.text)
```

I want to be guided in the right direction of how I might be able to put this together. I know I'll need to make some sort of if function obviously. I am using python3 in text editor and of course mac os terminal as well as Twitter's Developers apps.

Comment: Guiding you through the process of developing your bot is not a service we can offer here. If you have a *specific* question, you are welcome to ask.